# SharePoint 2013 apps development

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-apps

Basically I’m a .net developer and new into SharePoint 2013 apps.
We have 12 SharePoint applications and hosted in Microsoft cloud. In the beginning it was developed in SharePoint 2010 then migrated to 2013 and hosted in cloud. Now Microsoft has removed all FTC code and requested us to develop SharePoint apps with on-premises environment. I want know how many Apps need to be developed for 1 SharePoint applications? Can I use 1 app for multiple business requirements? Please anyone clarify me.    Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is depended on your business solution whether you want to create one app (provider hosted app with different client app parts) or multiple app for different solutions.
For ex:- I want to create a portal which have announcement/carousal/show employee details. Then we can create one provider hosted app with different client app part and placed on the host web.

If your solution is not much complex then you can easily go with one provider/SharePoint hosted app. Rest is your decision.